# Xamarin : Error XALNK7000 when shared runtime is disabled

Tags: xamarin, build, hyperlink, release

```
Erreur      Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.String Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.ViewPath::NormalizePath(System.String)' in assembly: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.InplaceStringBuilder
   à Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
   à Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   à MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   à Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   à Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   à Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
   à Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   à Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   à Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   à Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   à MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   à Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   à Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   à MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   à Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   à Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
   à Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()    TabbedPageWithNavigationPage.Droid
```

My app Works fine when Shared Runtime is enabled but I can't deploy it with that configuration.
I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and Xamarin.Forms v5.0.0.2012

Thanx

Comment: Maybe you can try to delete obj and bin folder, then restart vs.

Comment: Hi, ThanQ but I already did it and it doesn't work

Comment: The problem is relative to this Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.InplaceStringBuilder even if I delete the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc , I get another error with another AspNetCore nuget . A similar issue : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29062
Thanx for helping btw

Comment: so you have solution about your problem now?

Comment: Hi Cherry, no I'm trying to make a migration to .Net 5. Still I investigated for a while, I opened the DLL that was making the error. Microsoft.Net.Http.headers.dll In Which there is the InplaceStringBuilder (Extensions.Primitives), but the problem is that new nugets don't use the InplaceStringBuilder function. So VS can't resolve that because there is no more use of it. I'm still trying to solve it , I'll come back when it's done. But As a new dev I tried to migrate from Netstandard 2.0 to 5, I struggle a bit could you guide me a bit?

Comment: For anyone who is struggling with this error. Set VS Link Assemblies to "None" and adapt your code. I've been looking for another workaround with that config for 2 months but nothing works. Don't waste your time, improvise, adapt, overcome. Thanx Cherry

Comment: you mean that setting  VS Link Assemblies to "None" , can solve your problem now?